# Expressions avec journée

Tags: expressions

Les questions concernent la vie en France :

1. À partir de quelle heure faut-il s'arrêter de dire **Bonne journée** ?
2. À partir de quelle heure peut-on dire **Bonne fin de journée** ?
3. Peut-on employer l'expression **Bonne reste de journée** ?

L'adjectif bon(ne) peut se remplacer par excellent(e) ou ce dernier-ci semblerait trop lourd ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les réponses sont personnelles, certains ne disent jamais "Bonne fin de journée" et restent sur "Bonne journée", d'autres utilisent "Bonne soirée"... Cela dépend de la personne et du contexte.

Pour répondre à tes questions:

1. Je dirais vers 18h, l'heure à laquelle on finit le travail mais il n'y a aucune règle fixe.
2. Je dirais à partir de midi si on sait qu'on ne va pas reparler à la personne avant le soir.
3. L’expression correcte serait "Bon reste de journée" (reste est masculin) mais je ne l'ai jamais entendue.
4. On peut tout a fait utiliser "Excellente (fin de) journée" mais plus souvent à l'écrit qu'à l'oral.

Comment: "Bon reste de journée" ou "Bonne reste de journée" ne se dit pas d'après moi et je ne l'ai jamais entendu (étant français). "Bonne fin de journée" me semble bien plus correcte et veux dire la même chose.

Answer (score 1):

En Suisse, si on quitte le travail en milieu de matinée pour ne revenir que le lendemain, on peut lui dire "Bonne soirée". Mais c'est un clin d'oeuil rhétorique.